# How do you kick off a hadoop job programmatically?

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to hadoop. In the tutorials I've read, you package your code into a jar and then run the code via

```
yarn jar [jar]
```

I've got this to work, but what I'd like to do is to pass code to hadoop programmatically, dynamically. In other words, I have java code that is doing some processing, and I'd like to farm some of that processing out to a running hadoop cluster, get the answer back and incorporate it into my running java code. I'm sure there is a way to do this - apologies for not finding it in the documentation. What are my options?

Many thanks.

EDIT for clarification:  I am talking about say you have a web application for example, such that someone can go to a webpage, enter some text, that text becomes an argument for some hadoop job, like perhaps it becomes part of a text search that is done on a cluster and the results returned to the user. Then you would need some way to communicate with hadoop through some kind of client interface, rather than creating a jar and submitting the jar to hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0 shows how to do this through Java, with the key part for you being the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Comment: But your answer would be offline, I think? You would create this class, put it in a jar, and then execute the jar on hadoop. I am talking about say you have a web application for example, such that someone can go to a webpage, enter some text, that text becomes an argument for some hadoop job, like perhaps it becomes part of a text search that is done on a cluster and the results returned to the user. Then you would need some way to communicate with hadoop through some kind of client interface, rather than creating a jar and submitting the jar to hadoop? Sorry if this is what your answer is..

Comment: My answer would still be the most appropriate solution. Have the user's input sent to the Jar as an argument and have the Jar executed as the result of the user clicking a button?